# laradock настройка ssl

Tags: laravel, docker, ssl

Помогите пожалуйста разобраться с настройкой ssl на laradock..Сертификаты уже есть и я вроде нашёл папку /laradock/nginx/ssl/ (место где кажется они должны лежать) и скинул их туда. Но ничего не заработало..помогите найти наиболее простой путь(именно на ларадок) потому что обычный докер я не осилю..

Answer (score 1):

Решил вопрос поправив конфиг nginx по пути /laradock/nginx/sites/default.conf 
Раскомментировал эти 4 строчки (так-же можно изменить имя если сертификаты отличаются названием). 
Ранее закинул сертификаты в папку  /laradock/nginx/ssl/.

```
# For https
listen 443 ssl default_server;
listen [::]:443 ssl default_server ipv6only=on;
ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/default.crt;
ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/default.key;
```

Comment: Отметьте свой ответ решением.